# Ignore NTUSER.DAT files when ls on Git Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git, ls

I use Git Bash as my terminal on Windows. When I `ls` in my Home directory, I see some `NTUSER.DAT` entries, which I assume are system files. They don't appear when I run `dir` in the default Windows Prompt.

What can I do so the `ls` command ignore these entries in the Git Bash as well?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

After some digging, I found a way around it. I put the script below in my `.bashrc` file, so these settings load automatically with Git Bash. This piece of code was based on a [dotfiles](https://github.com/igetgames/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/main) project.

```
LS_COMMON="-hG"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON --color=auto"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I NTUSER.DAT\* -I ntuser.dat\*"

test -n "$LS_COMMON" &&
alias ls="command ls $LS_COMMON"
alias ll="ls -l"
alias la="ls -a"
alias lal="ll -a"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even know what I was missing!  Could you explain the test -n line?

Comment: It's testing whether the `$LS_COMMON` variable exists. If it exists, the next statement is going to be executed, i.e. `alias ls="command ls $LS_COMMON"` is going to be created.

Note that I based that snippet off the dotfiles that I liked in my original answer. At the time I didn't pay attention at what that line did, as I was just worried about getting it to work. Now that I come to think of, that might not be necessary at all, as the `$LS_COMMON` variable is defined just above.

I'll leave the answer unaltered, as it's a little bit hard for me to test if it works (don't use Windows anymore).

Comment: Ah I see.  Thanks!  I just tested it and it works fine for me without `test -n "$LS_COMMON" &&` using the newest version of git bash and fresh install of windows 10.  But I guess I'll leave it in.

Answer (score 3):

I added some folder patterns to the great (!) solution of thalesmello.
Those folders were disturbing me on Windows 7. Now, my home-folder in git bash is completely empty. This is it!

```
# refers to http://superuser.com/questions/650322/ignore-ntuser-dat-files-when-ls-on-git-bash
LS_COMMON="-hG"
# --color : On Windows7 this produces permission errors, e.g. for Music folder:
# LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON --color=auto"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I NTUSER.DAT\* -I ntuser.dat\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I AppData\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Music\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Pictures\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Start\ Menu\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Application\ Data\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Local\ Settings\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Cookies\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I ntuser.ini"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I ntuser.pol"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Thumbs.db"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Favorites\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Recent\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Searches\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Videos\*"
LS_COMMON="$LS_COMMON -I Desktop\*"
alias ls="command ls $LS_COMMON"
alias ll="ls -l"
alias la="ls -al"
```

Comment: +1 For being a useful extension to the top-rated answer, in the same spirit of decluttering Windows directory listings, and easily edited to taste.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to previous answers, a Windows 8.1 version:

Add your alias: `alias ls=ls_filter.bat $*`.
Save the following as `ls_filter.bat` somewhere along your `%PATH%`:

```
@REM Runs ls with a filter to exclude some Windows folders, but only when run from the user's home folder.
@if "%CD%" == "%USERPROFILE%" (
    ls --color^
        -I "AppData" -I "Contacts" -I "Favorites" -I "Links"^
        -I "Music" -I "My Documents" -I "Pictures" -I "Videos" -I "Saved Games" -I "Start Menu" -I "OneDrive"^
        -I "NTUSER.*" -I "ntuser.*" -I "thumbs.db" -I "Thumbs.db" -I "desktop.ini"^
        -I "Application Data" -I "Cookies" -I "NetHood" -I "PrintHood" -I "Local Settings"^
        -I "Recent" -I "Searches" -I "SendTo" -I "Templates" %*
) else (
    ls --color -I "NTUSER.*" -I "ntuser.*" -I "thumbs.db" -I "Thumbs.db" -I "desktop.ini" %*
)
```

This makes it so the filter only applies when you're in your home directory. When in other directories, folders like Music and Videos won't be filtered out.

All of these filters make `ls` a little slow for me (I'm using [Cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/)), so I've substituted my `ls` for a [faster version](https://u-tools.com/msls.asp) which takes the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias ls="ls --hide '[Nn][Tt][Uu][Ss][Ee][Rr]*'"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).